# elman recurrent neural network - choose number of neurons in context layer

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, forecasting

I have two time series data, $y$ and $x$. Suppose I want to forecast $y(t+1)$ from previous values $y(t)$, $y(t-1)$, $x(t)$, $x(t-1)$. I want to use an elman RNN.

From the examples given in the original article "[finding structure in time](https://crl.ucsd.edu/~elman/Papers/fsit.pdf)", the number of neurons in hidden and context layer are the same. First question: Is the number of neurons in hidden layer equals the number of neurons in context layer?

Second question: Again from the examples given in the article mentioned above, only one internal (previous) state is stored in memory. Therefore they used only one neuron in context layer. But I have to use 2 previous internal states. Should I use 4 neurons (For time series $x$ and $y$.If there is only time series $y: 4/2=2$ neurons) for values at $(t)$ and $(t-1)$ to forecast $(t+1)$ ?

Comment: @YuvalSp quite surprising that the posted DOI http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0364-0213(90)90002-E is 404

Comment: I have just edited it

Comment: yes thanks for that, but it defeats the purpose of DOI :-) not to mention that more than one DOI got assigned for this paper.